# How to pass type as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the below types checking code to verify if userInput is one of the defined value

```js
const variantColorValues = ['primary', 'black', 'green', 'red', 'white'] as const;
export type VariantColor = (typeof variantColorValues)[number];

function isOfTypeVariantColor(selectedColor: string): selectedColor is VariantColor {
  return (variantColorValues as readonly string[]).includes(selectedColor);
}

isOfTypeVariantColor('red') //true
isOfTypeVariantColor('purple') //false
```

The code above works great. However the code will bulk up if I implement same logic to other properties too, so I thought of turning `isOfTypeVariantColor` into a generic function.

```js
function isOfType(userInput: string, valueList: string[]): userInput is VariantColor {
  return (valueList as readonly string[]).includes(userInput);
}
```

And my problem now is that I'm not sure how to turn `userInput is VariantColor` where `VariantColor` becoming a parameter

Comment: What do you mean by `However the code will bulk up if I implement same logic to other properties too?`

Comment: @dwjohnston: Imagine I have 100 properties, there will be 100 functions defined to check `isOfTypexxx`. What I try to achieve is instead, just having single function, that takes in allowed `value` in array, with its `type`, and returns a boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```ts
// Make sure to make valueList readonly so you can use readonly arrays like variantColorValues
function isOfType<T, U extends T>(userInput: T, valueList: readonly U[]): userInput is U {
  return (valueList as readonly T[]).includes(userInput);
}

const string: string = 'red';
if (isOfType(string, variantColorValues)) {
    string; // VariantColor
}

const number: number = 0
if (isOfType(number, [1, 2, 3] as const)) {
    number; // 1 | 2 | 3
}
```

`T` is the user input type and you are checking if `userInput` is type `U`. For example, when using `isOfType` with `variantColorValues`, `T` would be `string` and `U` would be `VariantColor`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwE4EsFigYRAGxEgNQRwFcBTCGAXhgG0ByAB1QFtkBPegGhnoCMcCYAGtuvAOZIyZMGPpSAJnIDuACxRQy9ALowElUJCgBuAFBkAHo3ywo7RmRhFU6LLnzUYACjsOQAM3hkNAxsPEJicggASlowEhY+MiRtM1N-EjBgKBRwGBQIAHl-ABV7MgAeEp4AVRhLTTAFShKAPi8SCGSASTBGEigALhhqoNIyABkCoZgpBAVwHHYYGtptaOHOnr6B-Mo6gG9TGFmyKBIkMG9EcanoPUo5hbAlkbXogDoULNIFCg6ukhev0oNEzABfUymQz3aCoMDiYZw77iTzyMhKMwoQJeArFMoOLzIhE8RAuULuCLjGLRGBHE4nYniYwwAD0rKcwVcYXwpkh0PA93iiWSw2FSSQngADKZsd48aVyl5xckeLQAIw8ABMPAAzLp9DAYaDafSGSqkBDTEA)

---

**Edit:** Per Gerrit0's comment, you don't actually need two type parameters:

```ts
function isOfType2<T>(userInput: unknown, valueList: readonly T[]): userInput is T {
  return (value as readonly unknown[]).includes(userInput);
}
```

However, it won't pick up on this:

```ts
if (isOfType(number, variantColorValues)) {}
//                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type 'readonly ["primary", "black", "green", "red", "white"]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly number[]'.
//   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

if (isOfType2(number, variantColorValues)) {
  number; // never
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwE4EsFigYRAGxEgNQRwFcBTCGAXhgG0ByAB1QFtkBPegGhnoCMcCYAGtuvAOZIyZMGPpSAJnIDuACxRQy9ALowElUJCgBuAFBkAHo3ywo7RmRhFU6LLnzUYACjsOQAM3hkNAxsPEJicggASlowEhY+MiRtM1N-EjBgKBRwGBQIAHl-ABV7MgAeEp4AVRhLTTAFShKAPi8SCGSASTBGEigALhhqoNIyABkCoZgpBAVwHHYYGtptaOHOnr6B-Mo6gG9TGFmyKBIkMG9EcanoPUo5hbAlkbXogDoULNIFCg6ukhev0oNEzABfUzpTLZXJXArFMoOABMVXaWyBOxmmWEYBAyjAPBu5DuMyei2WJXem0BwN2BRGMCOJyk50u10ik2mD1O8wpMBxeIJ7y+PxIfwgAO2ILBpkhpkM92gqDA4mGyu+4k88jISjMKECXgRpXKXg1qqJwVcYXwRHGMWiTOOMHN4mMMAA9B6nFbQu4kHKoYrYPFEslhqGkkhPAAGUwG7zGpFkLyR5I8WgARh4yJ4AGZdPoYMHoo7mTA00h3V6YJmYAAfGDIhswPOB+OGpOmyuWlx+8J2qKlpmQhNGoomlGphJR3shNwDzkOp0nSsQ0xAA)

Comment: You don't need two generic parameters.

Comment: @cherryblossom: I don't see any code at `Playground link`

Comment: @Isaac The link works for me, even when I opened it in an incognito window. See if https://tsplay.dev/Gm333m works (it redirects to the same URL).

Comment: @cherryblossom: Works like charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done it:

```js
const variantColorValues = ['primary', 'black', 'green', 'red', 'white'] as const;
export type VariantColor = (typeof variantColorValues)[number];

const variantRoleValues = ["teacher", "student"] as const; 
export type VariantRole = (typeof variantRoleValues)[number];

// This possibly isn't needed, it could be just strings, but I think it's good to explicitly narrow the types. 
type PossibleVariants = VariantColor | VariantRole

function isOfType<T extends PossibleVariants>(value: string, arrayOfPossibleValues: readonly T[]) : value is T {
   return (arrayOfPossibleValues as readonly string[]).includes(value);
}
```

Demo of use:

```js
const t1  = "teacher"; // In this scenario typescript knows this is the narrowest type "teacher"

if (isOfType(t1, variantColorValues)){ // No error, this is what we want right? 
    if (t1 === 'red') { //t1 is of type never, it's annoying that this doesn't give you an error. 
     //see: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28982
    
    }
}

const t2  = "teacher" as VariantRole; // For demo purposes, lets say we don't know if this is "teacher" or "student"

if (isOfType(t2, variantColorValues)){ // No error, this is what we want right? 
    if (t2 === 'red') { // t2 is of type never
}

const t3  = "teacher" as string; // For demo purposes, we don't know what kind of string this is. 

if (isOfType(t3, variantColorValues)){ // No error, this is what we want right? 
    if (t3 === 'red') { // t3 is of type "red" |"black" ... 

    if (t3 === 'student') { // expected error:  This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"primary" | "black" | "green" | "red" | "white"' and '"student"' have no overlap.(2367)

    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwE4EsFigYRAGxEgNQRwFcBTCGAXhgG0ByAB1QFtkBPegGhnoCMcCYAGtuvAOZIyZMGPpSAJnIDuACxRQy9ALowElUJCgBuAFBkAHo3ywo7RmRhFU6LLnzUYACjsOQAM3hkNAxsPEJicggASlowEhY+MiRtM1NDaCCXDAAlXDIiUgpPWgAiTSFVZNKeUugSBRkoUt19GAyTGHMrGxhfR2cQqDycRxofezIArKGRgsiKWPjE5NTTU38SMGAoFHAYFAgAeX8AFUnB1zD8LwgyUZ2yBWukAC4YaFQwcWj3u4fNM93EgDpRLqFgTAAN6mGAwKRQEhIMDeRDZNzhQpRPSUKQIBTgHDsD5QL7iWjaaIAOhQ21IjQgt3uZEeQPC0TMAF91ocTucHOCMTd5E96NEYAB6CWk8imXlnC7BK7ArxMJGMUZiyUS-zEO7rA2mfowAAKIAgEBQAnm6MoNEFLxgAB8nErcvl1pttrt9vL+WQADynGCWTRgBSUM0Wq2jQUQAB8XkQRT+pNp4h4yCQCHYJyjlutWIo7zxBLARJgpwp4veyfIoMr0NhcIRSJRXizObz5oLsYWlDapcJxM+6erNLpDQoSYWHNM3J5xwVDlVijEaKGLyLMWMXT9k1V+gUR-XbqFESKO73S-9qoqwCqSFP6K3-Y5XXWHT6AEY4TRymQlTVLuUowAAkiiUDqJQEDADIwQgH0kywagjCwMIYAgMolBQYcDZQY4YBZlhFC2JMMAAUBSClDygRePuK5QN+PAbsqmJvtEULajAAByiHJEg+A8LhlB4WoCCwMojjKK48IoOIqhQAA-F0cJwigdFMdQVA0CKSjilxUpaXh0zGmAZBwMkPAaPQA5gJh7Dpn0qgSc5eEEhQsiwOIKCWTA7AgCQegogJ+BUqpanNnC3ILl+UAAEx-hR96PqUOKuuicwgRKMAAGIeI0LCIYw6rmhQPCjFAME5jAUkwGW9DoZhygHIEIkNpRD7VDAHh1IijQYDRcp0QxZA+PFLFnq+l7RJx3F8SGSCCUgwnQQ24mSdJsmoApykRepmmJTpulrgZ3EJQ2pnkeZllIPOn7gJkUAAMxJZ1qXpaO3zZXlBVkEVMAlUg1h3BAPB1Q1TVYbVLnobSCg9YEX3iG5okQOFtHeKNPjPZNL7Atus2GTlC2hStqPrbDtVbRgcm7SpUWtd4L3aSdopnaBLMmW15GlIoaVOqUAhCMIaVUuLH5qUzOOs7w9QDVAWrEyGVgsoCi3Le8lZrYYCgaHsKLKCgOA4HoOAyewuJkIiyK8LqOB3PQHy0nBzmOP0lD0KUzAoGwSDsALFHCyIgelJI0hgKH-POhRagaGQpRO+gCNe-LTSJzALl+ZhPW3YIjBUl48XPQAbAA7NE6xSzF6xAA)